# Active object affecting a table

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

I have a trigger on table for auditing. Anyways, in the trigger I want to get the exact database object or statement that is processing and affecting my table. My problem is that the trigger shows duplicate records are inserted in different days. I would like to know what object generated the duplicated record.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're specifically asking here. Can you post code and tell us what your goal is, what you've tried and where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK` function. This will return the entire call stack as a varchar2, which you could save as-is or process however you need to.

If you are on Oracle 12, there's a more handy UTL_CALL_STACK package which provides flexible call stack access. See [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_call_stack.htm#ARPLS74078)

Answer (score 0):

Use pragma autonomous_transaction and it should solve your purpose..